# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isLoggedIn() on null in

Tags: magento2, admin-controller

> di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save" type="Modulename\Complexgrd\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save" />
```

> Save.php

```
<?php 
namespace Modulename\Complexgrd\Controller\Adminhtml\Category;

class Save extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save
{

protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

    public function execute()
    {


        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */


        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        /*$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);*/

        $category = $this->_initCategory();

        if (!$category) {
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('catalog/*/', ['_current' => true, 'id' => null]);
        }

        $data['general'] = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $categoryPostData = $data['general'];

        $isNewCategory = !isset($categoryPostData['entity_id']);
        $categoryPostData = $this->stringToBoolConverting($categoryPostData);
        $categoryPostData = $this->imagePreprocessing($categoryPostData);
        $categoryPostData = $this->dateTimePreprocessing($category, $categoryPostData);
        $storeId = isset($categoryPostData['store_id']) ? $categoryPostData['store_id'] : null;

        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId);
        $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($store->getCode());

        $store->setCurrentStore($store->getCode());
        $parentId = isset($categoryPostData['parent']) ? $categoryPostData['parent'] : null;
        if ($categoryPostData) {
            $category->addData($this->_filterCategoryPostData($categoryPostData));
            if ($isNewCategory) {
                $parentCategory = $this->getParentCategory($parentId, $storeId);
                $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
                $category->setParentId($parentCategory->getId());
            }

            /**
             * Process "Use Config Settings" checkboxes
             */

            $useConfig = [];
            if (isset($categoryPostData['use_config']) && !empty($categoryPostData['use_config'])) {
                foreach ($categoryPostData['use_config'] as $attributeCode => $attributeValue) {
                    if ($attributeValue) {
                        $useConfig[] = $attributeCode;
                        $category->setData($attributeCode, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            $category->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId());

            if (isset($categoryPostData['category_products'])
                && is_string($categoryPostData['category_products'])
                && !$category->getProductsReadonly()
            ) {
                $products = json_decode($categoryPostData['category_products'], true);
                $category->setPostedProducts($products);
            }
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'catalog_category_prepare_save',
                ['category' => $category, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
            );

            /**
             * Check "Use Default Value" checkboxes values
             */
            if (isset($categoryPostData['use_default']) && !empty($categoryPostData['use_default'])) {
                foreach ($categoryPostData['use_default'] as $attributeCode => $attributeValue) {
                    if ($attributeValue) {
                        $category->setData($attributeCode, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             * Proceed with $_POST['use_config']
             * set into category model for processing through validation
             */
            $category->setData('use_post_data_config', $useConfig);

            try {
                $categoryResource = $category->getResource();
                if ($category->hasCustomDesignTo()) {
                    $categoryResource->getAttribute('custom_design_from')->setMaxValue($category->getCustomDesignTo());
                }

                $validate = $category->validate();
                if ($validate !== true) {
                    foreach ($validate as $code => $error) {
                        if ($error === true) {
                            $attribute = $categoryResource->getAttribute($code)->getFrontend()->getLabel();
                            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                                __('Attribute "%1" is required.', $attribute)
                            );
                        } else {
                            throw new \Exception($error);
                        }
                    }
                }

                $category->unsetData('use_post_data_config');

                $category->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the category.'));
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
                $this->_getSession()->setCategoryData($categoryPostData);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
                $this->_getSession()->setCategoryData($categoryPostData);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('Something went wrong while saving the category.'.$e->getMessage()));
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
                $this->_getSession()->setCategoryData($categoryPostData);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isLoggedIn() on null in 
/var/www/html/M2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:252 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/html/M2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(205): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->_processUrlKeys() #1 
/var/www/html/M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #2 
/var/www/html/M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Modulename\Complexgrd\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) #3 
/var/www/html/M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Modulename\\Comple...', 'dispatch', Object(Modulename\Complexgrd\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...') #4 
/var/www/html/M2/vendor/magento/module-backend/ in 
/var/www/html/M2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php on line 252
```

If any one idea please share and help me as soon as

Comment: did you tried to call that `isLoggedIn` function?

Comment: no i haven't call

Comment: Maybe any other module trying to call that method or by mistake someone has created di.xml under `etc/` folder.

Comment: di.xml is in adminhtml folder

Comment: is there any other module?

Comment: no, there isn't any module for admin controller

Comment: Same error here, found the problem & posted the solution

Answer (score 10):

If you need to declare `__construct()` method in your Admin controller then you should call

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    ...
) {

    parent::__construct($context);
    ...
}
```

In your case, you'd look at parent class **\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save** `__construct()` method to see which parameters you need to pass

Comment: super work , well done !!

Answer (score 3):

Change your constructor with below code:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory, 
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory, 
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory, 
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date $dateFilter, StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, 
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig = null)
   {
       $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
       parent::__construct($context, $resultRawFactory, $resultJsonFactory, $layoutFactory, $dateFilter, $storeManager, $eavConfig);
   }
```

Comment: please help : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371703/buy-now-button-not-clickable-in-plp-page